# Xml schema interfaces

Tags: java, inheritance, xsd

I'm attempting to write an XML schema to define some model classes to be used in jaxb in java.

I would like to be able to define an interface in the xsd but I've no idea how to do this.

For example a lot of my classes will have an attribute called id which is type xs:ID. They will have an attribute called ref which is type xs:IDREF and they will have an attribute called extRef which means that there is a refrence but the element is not specified in the given xml file.

Ideally this would be an interface when converted to java for two reasons.

1. The classes that implement this are not necessarily connected.
2. I would like to specify a different inheritance tree for some of these objects.

Example:

```
<!-- Utility type to be externally referenceable this is too keep all the 
    externally refrencable attributes in check -->
<xs:complexType name="ExternallyReferenceable" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="extRef" type="externalReference" />
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" />
    <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:IDREF" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ExternalCarPart">
    <xs:extension base ="ExternallyReferenceable" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="CarPart">
    <xs:extension base ="ExternalCarPart">
                     <xs:sequence>
                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="partName" />
                     </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="CarLamp">
    <xs:extension base ="ExternalCarPart">
                     <xs:sequence>
                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="glassPurity" />
                     </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
</xs:complexType>
```

So in the above example it would be better if exteranllyRefrencable was an interface, and if carpart was an interface.

This would allow CarLamp to inherit from lamp rather than external car part. BicycleLamp could also implement the externallyRefrencable interface and extend lamp also.

Please ask me for clarification if the question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, JAXB doesn't generate interfaces from XSD.

JAXB also supports generating XSD from Java classes.  I'm not sure what it does with interfaces in that regard, but perhaps you need to go at it in the opposite direction - begin with Java and generate XSD, though I'm not sure that will help you.